# local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find prime numbers of a 2D-list but I am faced with this Error:
"local variable 'y' referenced before assignment"
How can I fix it?

Before I wrote this code I was trying to solve the problem without a function, but there was another problem that I will question.

```py
a=[[1,2,3],[4,7]]
###
def prime_detection (n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        y=False
        if n%i==0:
            break
        else:
            y=True

    return y
###
d=[]
for i in a:
    g=[]
    for j in i:
        if prime_detection(j)==True:
            g.append(j)

    d.append(g)
```

I expect in "if prime_detection(j)==True" show me a result but I am faced with "local variable 'y' referenced before assignment"

Comment: There are lots of duplicate questions that explain this issue in more detail. In your case, you are defining `y` inside your loop but trying to return it outside your loop (if the loop is never entered, then `y` will never be defined). Try moving `y = False` before your loop.

Comment: @benvc to be clear, that isn't *inherently* a problem since python does not have block slope. It is a problem in this case if the loop body never executes, e.g. when `n == 2`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you're defining y in the for loop, then returning it from outside the loop. you'd need to define it at the function scope in order to have it be visible.

Comment: Loops don't have their own scope. The reason the variable is not defined is that the loop is never entered at all if `n <= 2`

Answer (score 1):

When `n <= 2`, the sequence `range(2, n)` is empty, so none of the lines assigning to `y` is executed.

I suspect you meant something like this:

```
def prime_detection(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

or even simpler:

```
def prime_detection(n):
    return all(n%i for i in range(2, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `y = False` at the start of your function.
That way, it will be a variable accessible to the whole function, and will be returned as `False` unless its value is changed within the loop.

You might also want to use `if` statements for 1 and 2 with their own `return` values, due to their mathematical behaviours as prime numbers (the former not being one because of being tricky - just quickly put, the latter being weird). i.e:

```py
if n==1:
    return False
if n==2:
    return True
#rest of script should be fine...
```